# How to think in terms of Netty when making a game server?

Tags: java, netty

I'm having trouble understanding how Netty works while creating my GameServer.  Right now, I just want to be able to group 2 Netty channels in a GameRoom.  Below shows the code for my thought process, however I will explain it here as well.

When someone connects, I want to pair them with another player.  If there is no one available, I want them to wait until there is someone available to play with.  Once there is someone available to play with, I want to stick them both into an instance of my game, using their Channels to send inputs and receive data from the server.

To get something working, I figured I'd just have the Game class simulate random inputs on the server-side and when it figures out who the winner is, it would send that to the two channels in that specific game room (That's what is trying to be modeled in the code below).

When I write to the Channel objects when the game is created, they are available and they work.  When I try to access them from the write method however, they are not available and show up as a null pointer exception.

I really am not sure how to use netty to it's potential and if there are any suggestions about improving this, please let me know.

Also, I know there is a Java Game Server built on top of Netty, but I would rather use Netty myself to implement my own server as a learning experience.

Thanks all

```
public class GameRoom extends Game {
    private OnlinePlayer p1;
    private OnlinePlayer p2;

    public GameRoom(Channel p1, Channel p2) {
        this.p1 = new OnlinePlayer("Tucker", p1);
        this.p2 = new OnlinePlayer("Bad Kid", p2);
        p1.writeAndFlush("Game Starting\n");
        p2.writeAndFlush("Game Starting\n");
        startGame();
    }   

    public void write(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);

        p1.getChannel().writeAndFlush(msg + "\n");
        p2.getChannel().writeAndFlush(msg + "\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void gameOver() {
        String msg = String.format("Winner is %s, with score of %d!", getManager().getWinner().getName(), getManager().getWinner().getScore());
        write(msg);
    }

}

public class GameServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {
    static final ChannelGroup channels = new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);
    static final HashMap<SocketAddress, GameRoom> gameRoomMap = new HashMap<SocketAddress, GameRoom>();
    static final LinkedList<Channel> queue = new LinkedList<Channel>();

    @Override
    protected void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String msg)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (Channel c: channels) {
            if (c != ctx.channel()) {
                System.out.println("Writing to other channels!");
                c.writeAndFlush("[" + ctx.channel().remoteAddress() + "] " + msg + '\n');
            } else {
                c.writeAndFlush("[you] " + msg + '\n');
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handlerAdded(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        super.handlerAdded(ctx);
        Channel c = ctx.channel();
        channels.add(c);
        if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Channel pair = queue.pop();
            GameRoom g = new GameRoom(c, pair);
        }
        else {
            queue.add(c);
        }
        System.out.println(channels);
    }

    @Override
    public void handlerRemoved(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        super.handlerRemoved(ctx);
        System.out.println("Removing");
        Channel c = ctx.channel();
        channels.remove(c);
    }   
}
```

Comment: I think you would get better response on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Didn't know that existed.  Thanks for the response, I'll try there as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should write into channel context your thread-safe implementation of ChunkedStream in netty IO thread, where request arrives. Also you should provide server updates via this object from game thread.

See [stream's package](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/stream/package-summary.html) documentation. Especially ChunkedWriteHandler and ChunkedStream.

Comment: Turns out I had to put the GameRoom class in it's own thread... Then it solved my issue.  But I will look into the ChunkedStream stuff as well!  As I'm sure that will save me issues in the future!  Thanks for the response!

Comment: Yes, GameRoom should be in separate thread. Also you should remember, that channels CANNOT be used outside handler directly. You are free to manipulate with your response object instead - this provides you with downstream connection. For upstream linkage you can attach player ID to channel on initial request and map further messages from this channel by this ID.

Comment: So use the ChunkedWriteHandler for sending data correct.  How would I go about attaching the playerID to the channel?  Create a HashMap?

Comment: Read section [Storing stateful information](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandlerContext.html) in channel handler context. You can set player ID with ctx.getAttr(PLAYER_ID_ATTR).set(UUID.randomUUID()). In your game center you will route corresponding messages into appropriate game rooms (e.g. with ConcurrentHashMap).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help.  Is there any helpful references that explain the workflow that you would suggest, other than Netty's documentation?  Like example code or a book or something?
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: There are a lot of examples in [Netty's documentation](http://netty.io/wiki/). And in [source code](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example).